# Can't update belongs_to relationship in migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, belongs-to

I have the following model :

```
Class User::Basic
  belongs_to: group

Class Group
  has_many: users
  class_name: "::User::Basic",
  foreign_key: "group_id"
```

I also have a `User::Admin` class, which does not belongs to the group class (group_id equals -1)

I have an existing database where groups do not exist. I am trying to edit the group of basic users through the migrations.

In my migrations I have :

```
add_column :users, :group_id, :integer, :default => -1  #so that when a group_id is not specified, the user is ranked as admin

# I create groups 1,2,3 and 4 and then :

User.find(21, 3, 8, 17, 16, 18, 14, 19, 23, 25, 26).each do |usr|
  usr.update_attributes(group_id: 2)
end
User.find(11, 13, 20, 9).each do |usr|
  usr.update_attributes(group_id: 1)
end
User.find(15,22).each do |usr|
  usr.update_attributes(group_id: 3)
end
User.find(24).update_attributes(group_id: 4)
```

But all users still have a group_id of -1 after running the migrations. I tried to run the last bit in a console and it worked, so does anybody knows why this is not working in migrations ?

Comment: Try `usr.group_id = 2; usr.save!`. It will return true, if record saved successfully, else throw validation error, if any.

Comment: I tried that and I had a validation error.

Comment: Edit : I tried again, got no error but it didn't work in migrations, although it worked fine in a console.

Comment: Is `usr.save!` returns `true`?

Comment: In the console `usr.save!` is returning `true`, how can I know for in the migrations ?

Comment: Post your migration file, I think I know your issue

Comment: I'm sorry, there's field I can't reveal (professionnal secret), but I can give you the main structure :

File 1 :
Adding groups_id column to users' table

File 2 : 
Creating groups
Updating users'group

Answer (score 2):

**Console**

I personally would not include the data-specific calls in a [*migration*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migration-overview), it's simply not what the migrations are for:

> Migrations are a convenient way to alter your database schema over
>   time in a consistent and easy way. They use a Ruby DSL so that you
>   don't have to write SQL by hand, allowing your schema and changes to
>   be database independent.
>
> You can think of each migration as being a new 'version' of the
>   database. A schema starts off with nothing in it, and each migration
>   modifies it to add or remove tables, columns, or entries. Active
>   Record knows how to update your schema along this timeline, bringing
>   it from whatever point it is in the history to the latest version.
>   Active Record will also update your db/schema.rb file to match the
>   up-to-date structure of your database.

I wouldn't mention this if you were using a sweeping statement such as `User.all` etc, but as you're selecting individual records (with the `find` method), you'll make your migrations VERY data-specific, which isn't what they're for

> If you push this to production, and have different `ids`, how will it
>   work?

Simply **don't perform database requests in your migration**

--

I would recommend making your migration specifically for your column:

```
#db/migrate/your_migration.rb
class YourMigration
   def change
      add_column :users, :group_id, :integer, :default => -1
   end
end
```

*Then* once this has run, you'll want to [use the rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) to perform the data-specific fixes you want:

> rails c

```
groups = {"1" => [11, 13, 20, 9], "2" => [21, 3, 8, 17, 16, 18, 14, 19, 23, 25, 26], "3" => [15,22], "4" => [24]}

groups.each do |group, users|
  usr = User.find(users)
  usr.update_attributes(group_id: group)
end
```

Comment: Ok @RichPeck, thanks for your advice, I'll do everything in the console. For the data-specific side of the matter, I'm always using the last version of the production database for my devlopment, so the numbers would be the same in dev and prod.

Comment: @user284130 Keep in mind that this change will be unable to replicate on other devs machines. You may create a rake task and print instruction for running it on the end of the migration file

Comment: Thanks @RAJ..., I'll try that. Still, I can't explain why modifications are not working on `Users`, as they are working on objects created in the migration file.

Comment: @RichPeck, it is working in the console, I think I'll use the console. Yet, I still don't know why it's not working in the migrations if the object is not created in the migrations, and why it is working fine on console or on objects created in the migrations.

Comment: As explained, your migrations are for database operations. You need to use the console, or set up a script to handle the change you want with the data itself

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we run the migrations, rails resets the columns information about the tables, after completion of the execution of migration file.

In your case, you are trying to access the column before the completion of migration file execution. So, you need to call [`reset_column_information`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information) explicitly before operating on the column you have just added from the same migration file.

**Here is an example:**

```
def change
  add_column :users, :name, :string

  User.reset_column_information

  User.all.each do |u|
    u.name = 'user name'
    u.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried but it's still not working. I think it might have if I had had a no column error such as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115347/model-reset-column-information-does-not-reload-columns-in-rails-migration. 

Also, I've created the column in a different file, that might explain why your idea is not working.