# How to refresh the database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I inserted a column in mysql using my terminal then in rails I tried to get the columns,

```
puts (Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { self.table_name = 'sample_tables'}).column_names
```

but it will not show the inserted column. I need to refresh my rails first to show it. What code do I need to add to refresh the connection before getting the columns?

I tested it using `rails c`. Thanks in advance for the help.

BTW, I tried this

```
(Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { self.table_name = 'sample_tables'}).reload
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Have you checked out this post? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728033/4339299

Comment: Did you add a column using a Rails migration, or did you try to run DDL through the mysql client?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but have you run your migrations again after editing your database

Comment: I added the column in mysql not using migration. I also add column using this `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` 
 
Is it safe after the execute I will run this `(Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { self.table_name = 'sample_tables'}).connection.schema_cache.clear!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method "**column_names**" fetch names only once, and after always return old values.

```
def column_names
  @column_names ||= columns.map { |column| column.name }
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/column_names/class

Try to use "**reset_column_information**" method for cleanup `@column_names`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reset_column_information/class

Comment: And if it's Rails 3 application, you have to execute `YourClass.connection.schema_cache.clear!`

Comment: I am using Rails 4.2.3.. is it safe to run this `connection.schema_cache.clear!` ? Is it safe to clear column caches while rails app is running ?

Comment: Definitely safety, it's only variables cleanup ever for 4 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaCache.html#method-i-clear-21 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4e83815ce991efce2b84aa570f6673227ff0bb0d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb#L55-L61

Comment: Thanks.. I am using now :D I didn't use reset_column_information. I used only `connection.schema_cache.clear!` before getting`(Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { self.table_name = 'sample_tables'}).column_names`