# Add column in rails migration but column doesn't exist right away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I have an old migration that adds a column into a table, then immediate add some data in that column.

```
def change
  add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string

  TableName.create(
    column_name: "some string"
  )
end
```

Now, whenever I have to rerun `rake db:migrate` after dropping the database, I get this error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `column_name=' for #< TableName:0x007fa483a18838>

This migration worked when it was initially created, why doesn't it work if I rerun this migration?

I understand this isn't a great practice, but my research indicates that this should still work.

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115347/model-reset-column-information-does-not-reload-columns-in-rails-migration ?

Comment: perfect, that worked. thanks @fanta

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to make data changes within migrations. It it usually anti-pattern. It is recommended to do data migration inside a rake task:

```
namespace :table_names do
  task :create_first_table_name do
    TableName.create(
      column_name: "some string"
    )
  end
end
```

Read [Data Migrations in Rails](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/data-migrations-in-rails) if you want to know more about data migrations

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613312/1949363 is a solid response and typically a great pattern to follow.

Alternatively, if the data must be there for the migration to keep the app in a valid state, you could write raw SQL in the migration and insert data using

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(...)`