# Using renamed columns in a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In Rails 6.1, I would like to rename a column and convert the underlying data in a single migration:

```
class RestructureExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  
  def up
    rename_column :examples, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
    Example.reset_column_information
    Example.find_each do |example|
      unless example.new_column_name.nil?
        if example.new_column_name == 100
          example.new_column_name = 300
        else
          example.new_column_name = (example.new_column_name.to_f * 2.989).to_i
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    # Do the reverse - left out for brevity
  end

end
```

Even after adding `reset_column_information` (from the docs: "Resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request."), this throws `` NoMethodError: undefined method `new_column_name' ``.

The record `example` still has `old_cloumn_name`. I was expecting that the column information is updated in the database and the model after calling `rename_column` together `with reset_column_information`.

I can see in the [sources](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb#L437) that `rename_column` performs an alter table SQL command. Checking the column names via SQL after `rename_column` reveals that the column is renamed correctly. So, I assume that only the model holds outdated information.

Probably there are several workarounds (use SQL instead of model, do the rename after converting the data, use two separate migrations, ...), but I would prefer my approach for comprehensibility.

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#renaming-a-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an anwser to my own question. As suggested in the [migrations guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations), it is possible to use a local model in combination with `reset_column_information`:

```
class RestructureExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  
  class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
  
  def up
    rename_column :examples, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
    Example.reset_column_information
    Example.find_each do |example|
      unless example.new_column_name.nil?
        if example.new_column_name == 100
          example.new_column_name = 300
        else
          example.new_column_name = (example.new_column_name.to_f * 2.989).to_i
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def down
    # Do the reverse - left out for brevity
  end

end
```

This approach worked for me.

Comment: In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115347/model-reset-column-information-does-not-reload-columns-in-rails-migration), it was suggested to add ```Example.connection.schema_cache.clear!```. For me, this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename it inside `change_table` if you want it to work as you are using it now.

```rb
change_table :examples do |t|
  t.rename :old_name, :new_name
end

Example.reset_column_information
# ....
```

Comment: I think it has to be ```t.rename```. Unfortunately, I still get the same ```NoMethodError``` as soon as I try to access ```new_column_name```.

Comment: Yeah, `rename`. It's strange, it works for me straight away.